# extract objects and flatten them

Tags: javascript

I've got an array of data from an API called `content` that needs to have its shape transformed as shown in the console output.  Essentially, the objects within each formula array need to be pulled out and put into a `formulas` array but they need to carry along the `role` and `id` attributes of their parent object.

While the `.forEach()` with a nested `.map()` approach produces the desired output, I'm wondering if there's a better way to write this logic.

```js
// data from API
const content = [
    { role: 'row', id: 0, expressions: { formula: [ { id: 'L34', name: 'CommodityName' }, { id: 'L4', name: 'ItemId' } ] } },
    { role: 'column', id: 1, expressions: { formula: [ { id:'LC', name: 'Year' }, { id: 'LA', name: 'Month' } ] } },
    { role: 'body',  id: 2, expressions: { formula: [ { id:'L1B', name: 'Demand' } ] } }
];

// logic to extract and flatten
const formulas = [];
content.forEach(o => {
    const data = o.expressions.formula.map((x) => ({ contentId: o.id, role: o.role, ...x }) );
    formulas.push(...data);
});

// look at results
const pretty = (data) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
// console.log(pretty(content));
console.log(pretty(formulas));
```

Comment: Tiny bit of code, that seems to perform its task admirably. Not much we can add.

Comment: I'm curious about possibilities to accomplish the same with `Object.assign()` or maybe `.flatMap()`.

Comment: No review just for you for your information: This can be done with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap): `const formulas = content.flapMap(o => o.expressions.formula.map(...));`.

Comment: Possibly, but there will be very little between these solutions. In the end there will be 2 loops, overt or hidden, going over the array, and generate the output. Let's see if someone picks up the gauntlet. Ah, I spoke too late.

Comment: @RoToRa - Beautiful!  Had to make 1 small change `.flatMap` instead of `.flapMap`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It is better than original code because of 2 points:

- We don't need to create an additional variable to show answer (`newArr` in my example is just for clear code, we can also not to use it and `console.log` the result directly)
- In original code we use `array.map` method to save the "mutated" array in another variable and then destructing it so we have 2 loops. But we can do it with 1 loop, we just need to get each item in array and put it to another array without saving it anywhere

So I think that my example is less complex and faster.

P.S. I also think that we don't need `pretty` variable.

```js
const content = [
    { role: 'row', id: 0, expressions: { formula: [ { id: 'L34', name: 'CommodityName' }, { id: 'L4', name: 'ItemId' } ] } },
    { role: 'column', id: 1, expressions: { formula: [ { id:'LC', name: 'Year' }, { id: 'LA', name: 'Month' } ] } },
    { role: 'body',  id: 2, expressions: { formula: [ { id:'L1B', name: 'Demand' } ] } }
];


const newArr = content.reduce((formulas, contentItem) => {
  contentItem.expressions.formula.forEach(formulaItem => formulas.push({
    contentId: contentItem.id,
    role: contentItem.role,
    ...formulaItem
  }));
  return formulas;
}, [])

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Answer (score 1):

The original version is clear, but you can avoid the unnecessary mutation and assign to `formulas` in a single statement using a flat map.

```
const formulas = content.flatMap(o =>
  o.expressions.formula.map(
    (x) => ({ contentId: o.id, role: o.role, ...x })
  )
)
```

For older versions of JS that don't have the `flatMap` built in, there is a flat map idiom using `Array.concat`:

```
[].concat(...x.map(f))
```

where `x.map(f)` returns a possible nested array.  This will flatten the array 1 level, which is typically all you need.

In your case, this becomes:

```
const formulas = [].concat(
  ...content.map(o => o.expressions.formula.map(
    (x) => ({ contentId: o.id, role: o.role, ...x })
  ))
)
```

Comment: Your solution works.  I was also able to get `flatMap` to work as follows: `const formulas = content.flatMap(o => o.expressions.formula.map((x) => ({ contentId: o.id, role: o.role, ...x }) ));`

Comment: Ah yes, that's better. I forgot they had added it to the standard library.